# setText() called from SubClass instance returns NULLPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-view, android-custom-view

I am developing an android application which requires to set the default font family(typeface) of the TextView to Roboto, I extended the TextView and defined the typeface to be Roboto-Light.tff but the application crashes with a NullPointerException. Here is the Class:

```
public class RobotoTextView extends TextView {

public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);

    // Eclipse edit mode doesn't show the font
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }

    if(attrs != null) {
        TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RobotoTextView);
        String fontName = styledAttrs.getString(R.styleable.RobotoTextView_typeface);
        styledAttrs.recycle();

        if (fontName != null) {
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
            setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }           
} 
}
```

Here is my XML attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="RobotoTextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="string" />
</declare-styleable></resources>
```

here is the code where at line 54 the exception is thrown, knowing that the parameter supplied is not null.

[image]

and here is the error:

[image]

here is the drawer_list_item.xml:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<com.mhproductions.widget.RobotoTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    app:typeface="Roboto-Light"/>

<com.mhproductions.widget.RobotoTextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"
    app:typeface="Roboto-Light"/>
```

Comment: show `drawer_list_item.xml`

Comment: `RobotoTextView` is irrelevant, because it's never used in your code.

Comment: it seams your layout xml does not have text view with title id

Comment: No I have used RobotoTextView and when I aimed to use setText() the error appears

Comment: You didn't used RobotoTextView, you declared txtTitle as TextView, which is causing the problem, which makes RobotoTextView irrelevant. Please post drawer_list_item.xml as @Raghunandan said.

Comment: Even when I use RobotoTextView the error persists

Comment: Even passing literal string text give this error, I don't know where is this bug

Comment: @Raghunandan I have posted the drawer_list_item.xml

Comment: @Mahmoud what is line 54 of adapter?

Comment: @Raghunandan is is shown in the first figure, the Text assignment method

Comment: @Mahmoud what is line 54? which line is it?

Comment: @Raghunandan cannot you see the figure ?????????

Comment: `txtTitle` is null. You do not have a TextView with id `title` in the xml layout. hence the `NullPOinterException`

Answer (score 0):

It slooks like getTitle() is returning null.  I never understand people who have an error they don't understand and assert, up front, that everything about the code is correct.

I think it must be getTitle() because of the getIcon() completion in the line above 54.

Comment: rcook I have told you that the parameter is not null, I have used another approach which is removed dependency on Custom View (RobotoTextView) and everything goes ok, except in this case

Comment: Yes, I know you have told me/us the parameter is not null.  But you are getting a null pointer exception.  Which do you think is more likely: that you are mistaken and there is a null parameter, or that you have the only environment in the world where Java reports a null pointer exception when there is not one?  You have offered no evidence that the parameter is not null, you've just told us that it is not while in the middle of asking us for help because you don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Well lastly I solved the problem on my own, and thanks that you understood the problem :) I think they must block non-patient people here, just seeking the points must no be the goal here.

Comment: This is a good example of why some of us just skip questions when they seem to come from people who assert so definitely that "everything is correct".  I note you're being coy about what was wrong.

Comment: Please roock sit back and stop wasting my time to reply on your silly comments and try to be better you look to br depressed ot something like this

Comment: I am at present encountering a situation where the debugger says a field is not null, I have a "if (foo != null)" check around it, and I still get a NPE. The debugger automatically stops prior to the NPE inside my anti-null check and reports foo as not null.  So, rcook, he's not the only one running into Java lying.

Comment: it is certainly possible, but the chances of it are exceedingly small.  I would be interested in what you find out it actually is; I would have been interested in his, too, but he isn't telling what he found, making me suspect it is something he doesn't want to admit.  After all, "everything is correct".

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure R.layout.drawer_list_item has a TextView with id R.id.title

**2) Implement all three constructors in RobotoTextView**

3) Make sure navDrawerItems are instantiated and they contain no null items.

Comment: I did implement the 3 constructors but it didn't helped.

Comment: Just find out what value is null. It's either txtTitle or navDrawerItems or navDrawerItems.get(position).